# The group morphism of tye ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Let $(G,+,\cdot)$ $(H,+,\cdot)$ be rings, we suppose that the unites $(G*,\cdot)$ and $(H*,\cdot)$ form groups respectively, for example, the matrix ring $M(n,\mathbb{R})$. There is a group morphism $\phi: (G,\cdot)\to (H,\cdot)$, then is it $\phi(-\textrm{id})=-\textrm{id}$?

Comment: If $R$ is a ring, then it doesn't necessarily form a group under multiplication.

Comment: You don't have to specify that the set of units forms a group (as you edited to do in the first line), you have to change  $(G,\cdot)$ to $(G^\ast,\cdot)$ and $(H,\cdot)$ to $(H^\ast,\cdot)$. As I commented earlier, if $(G,\cdot)$ is a group, then $G=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If a ring homomorphism is required to send $1_G$ to $1_H$, then $\phi(-1_G)+1_H=\phi(-1_G)+\phi(1_G)=\phi(1_G-1_G)=\phi(0)=0$, so $\phi(-1_G)=-1_H$.

If $\phi$ is merely a group homomorphism between the groups of units $G^\ast$ and $H^\ast$, then the answer is trivially "no": you could map $\phi(g)=1_H$ for every $g\in G^\ast$ to provide a counterexample.